# Error with visualization of apache beam interactive_beam on jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, apache-beam

Currently, i'm learning with apache beam on jupyter notebook. I've try the code below and try to display the output with interactive_beam, but when i try to run .show() the header of the notebook itself seem clunky and overly enlarged and no display output.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_runner import InteractiveRunner
import apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam as ib

with beam.Pipeline(InteractiveRunner()) as p:
input_data = p | beam.Create([1,2,3,4,5])
ib.show(input_data)
```

[Image of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Zwr.png)

Comment: Could you find any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

try using `ib.collect(input_data)`, it solved it for me

Source: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dataflow-notebooks-streamingwordcount#4